# Wrap STL vector and change behavior of its iterator

Tags: c++, stl

There is such code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class A{
public:   
    class iterator : public  std::vector<T>::iterator{
    public:
        T& operator*(){
            ??
        }
    };

    iterator begin(){
        return v.begin(); // error
    }

    iterator end(){
        return v.end(); // error
    }

    void add(const T& elem){
        v.push_back(elem);
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> v;
};

int main() {
    A<int> a;
    a.add(2);
    a.add(4);
    for(A<int>::iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it){
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is a wrapper for `std::vector` with my own additional functions. I would like to use `std::vector`'s iterator, however I want only to change behavior of `operator*` for iterator:

```
T& operator*(){
  // do some additional function
  // normal behavior, return value of some element in vector
            ??
}
```

How can I use `std::vector` and its iterator with modification of only `operator*`? I would like also to wrap functions like `begin()` and `end()` for iterator, how to wrap them properly?

EDIT:

Using tips from answers in this topic, I managed to solve my problem in following way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class A {
public:

    class iterator : public std::vector<T>::iterator {
    public:

        iterator(typename std::vector<T>::iterator c) : std::vector<T>::iterator(c) {
        }

        T& operator*() {
            std::cout << "Im overloaded operator*\n";
            return std::vector<T>::iterator::operator *();
        }
    };

    iterator begin() {
        return iterator(v.begin());
    }

    iterator end() {
        return iterator(v.end());
    }

    void add(const T& elem) {
        v.push_back(elem);
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> v;
};

int main() {
    A<int> a;
    a.add(2);
    a.add(4);

    for (A<int>::iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end() ; ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe it will be helpful for someone.

Comment: Yup.  I misread the code.  Not sure how that happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping stdlib iterators is done best with iterator adaptors. This task is far from trivial and there is the [Boost.Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) library to simplify the task. Maybe one of the provided iterators already solves your problem.

If you are going to write this on your own (I **really** don't recommend this), you should implement your own iterator and have it be constructible from a `vector::iterator`, then overload all required operators to meet the requirements of the concept that your new iterator models. Also inherit from `std::iterator` to get the traits working. Don't forget to have the a const variant. [This book](http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/) has a chapter devoted to developing your own iterators. Also get a copy of the standard (C++03 or C++11, doesn't matter much here). You are going to need it.

Comment: He also needs to implement a wrapper for `std::vector` if he wants to use it transparently (which his question suggests).

Comment: @BjörnPollex The class looks like he is only going to need an adaptor. His class seems not to be intended as a full model of `Sequence` and exposing `begin()` and `end()` should only require iterators.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only way to do this is to write a complete wrapper for `std::vector` and its iterator-types. This is a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

One does not inherit from `std::vector<T>::iterator` since it does not need to be a class. In some implementations this is just a typedef for `T*`, and one cannot inherit from a pointer. One also shouldn't inherit from standard containers as they lack a virtual destructor; a possibility is to inherit in a `private` or `protected` way and make all symbols and functions visible by means of `typedef` and `using`. In the end, you will have to rewrite the entire vector and its iterators that forward calls to the base implementation.

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer here is most likely that you **shouldn't** change the behaviour of operator* for an iterator. Operator overloading should be done only in cases where it is so extremely intuitive that anyone reading the code that uses the operator would automatically know what is happening. An example of this would be if you had a matrix class and overloaded operator+. When someone sees you adding two matrix objects together, they can easily know what is happening.

When dereferencing an iterator however, there is no intuitive sense of what the additional side effects will be for your class.

Comment: Oh, changing the behaviour of `operator*` can be extremely useful. Think `transformation iterators`.